# Android: DatePickerDialog inputs current date only and not chosen date

Tags: java, android, date, datepicker

I am making a date picker dialog in where a user will pick a date and send it to the database. Problem is whenever I use the dialog it only puts the current date and not the date chosen

Code snippets:

```
searchField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);  
        final Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                    int dayOfMonth) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                updateLabel();
            }

        };
searchField.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {

                new DatePickerDialog(Attendance.this, date, myCalendar
                      .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
            }
        });

private void updateLabel() {

        String myFormat = "yyy-MM-dd"; //In which you need put here
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);

        searchField.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
        }
```

Comment: this is not valid code (no comma after fgg, what does it even mean?): new DatePickerDialog(Attendance.this, date, myCalendar
                        .get(Calendar.YEAR), fgg
                        myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();

Comment: what is `fgg` in `DatePickerDialog`? And `DatePickerDialog` has 5 parameters and you have set only 4. Where is monthOfYear?

Comment: it was an error in copying sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my `DatePickerDialog` I have set `onClickListener()` on `textView` use it in your app, it works very well.

```
int mYear, mMonth, mDay;

final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

dateView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date_view);
dateView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(MyActivity.this,
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
                        c.set(year, month, day);
                        String date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(c.getTime());
                        dateView.setText(date);

                       mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                       mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                       mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                    }
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            dpd.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but why is it that at line 17 when the variables are being called it shows an error? Its says the variables were not created

Comment: @funnystuff `c` is an **Object** of `Calendar` class. You have defined it as `myCalendar` in your code. Accept the answer if it really helped you.

Comment: @funnystuff would you please tell me where exactly instead of line 17?

Comment: }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);

Comment: @funnystuff those are integer values, see I have edited my answer.

Comment: thank you but the }, mYear, mMonth, mDay); is still getting an error line it says that it cannot be resolved into a variable?

Comment: @funnystuff see I again made a change to answer. Change is at top of code and bottom of code as well. I have removed `int` from `int mYear` `int mMonth` `int mDay` at bottom. And you can see the change at top of code too.